# How to migrate TFS 2008 Project Version Control to TFS 2010?

Tags: version-control, migration, version-control-migration

I have Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 installed on my company since tree years. I installed TFS 2010 and I want to migrate the version control from 2008 to 2010.
I tried to use [Team Foundation Server Integration Tools (March 2011 Release)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f854dd59-8eeb-4673-8d9a-ae012989bfa2) but I've got an error/conflict when I tried to migrate:

> The target server http://tfs2008:8080/
>   is not a TFS2010 server

I don't know why it says target and not source even I've putted it (tfs 2008) on the left source!!

Can anyone any idea what's going on?

Thank you and Kind Regards.

Comment: Maybe you could share your Settings to check it

Comment: The ones used in the TFS IP session (you can export them to an XML using the TFS GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to migrate from the tfs 2008 server, I ran the TFS integration tool from 2008 and it worked.